# Custom MediaControls in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I copied the MediaController.java file from androidSDK.

Next i have taken  the VideoView class from androidSDK in my application.

I sorted out the various Bugs, but one , and thats the PolicyManager.

i want to know what is exactly Policy Manager class , why the Default MediaController class is using it .

or is there any other way to create Custom Media Controller...plz dont tell to inflate an xml on videoView..
thanx for your cooperation and valuable answers.

Comment: Here is an example MediaController customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller/14323144#14323144

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaController` uses the `PolicyManager` to create a new overlay window. That's all. If (like me) you write for custom hardware and have no qualms about doing the same thing in native code, it's pretty easy. If you would rather keep away from the private API, you'll need to go another route. You should be able to use `Dialog` or `SurfaceView` without much trouble. There's a `SurfaceView` example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049447/custom-mediacontrols-in-android).